# How to do nested Group By with Annotation in django orm?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

I have the following data:

```
publisher                    title
--------------------------  -----------------------------------
New Age Books                Life Without Fear
New Age Books                Life Without Fear
New Age Books                Sushi, Anyone?
Binnet & Hardley             Life Without Fear
Binnet & Hardley             The Gourmet Microwave
Binnet & Hardley             Silicon Valley
Algodata Infosystems         But Is It User Friendly?
Algodata Infosystems         But Is It User Friendly?
Algodata Infosystems         But Is It User Friendly?
```

Here is what I want to do: I want to count how many books of the same titles are published by each author.
I want to get the following result:

```
{publisher: New Age Books, title: Life Without Fear, count: 2},
{publisher: New Age Books, title: Sushi Anyone?, count: 1},
{publisher: Binnet & Hardley, title: The Gourmet Microwave, count: 1},
{publisher: Binnet & Hardley, title: Silicon Valley, count: 1},
{publisher: Binnet & Hardley, title: Life Without Fear, count: 1},
{publisher: Algodata Infosystems, title: But Is It User Friendly?, count: 3}
```

My solution goes something along the lines of:

```
query_set.values('publisher', 'title').annotate(count=Count('title'))
```

But it is not producing the desired result.

Comment: `query_set.values('publisher', 'title').annotate(count=Count('pk')).order_by('publisher', 'title')`.

Comment: Hey! thank you so much.It worked. Can you please explain your answer a bit?

Comment: it is actually more  a peculiarity of Django that forces the fields to be added to a `GROUP BY` clause. It might make more sense to add a `.group_by` clause I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a peculiarity in Django that will not perform a `GROUP BY` on the values without an `.order_by()` clause. You can thus add an `.order_by()` clause and process this with:

```
query_set.values('publisher', 'title').annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('publisher', 'title')
```

By ordering the items "fold" into a group and we thus count the number of primary keys for each group.